# alternative to oauth2 (Python module) on GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, twitter, twitter-oauth, oauth-2.0

From my app running on GAE, I want to be able to post tweets periodically.

I've a code with which I am able to post tweets from localhost.

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import simplejson as json
import oauth2 as oauth 

consumer_key = ""
consumer_key_secret = ""
oauth_token = ""
oauth_token_secret = ""

consumer = oauth.Consumer(key=consumer_key, secret=consumer_key_secret)
access_token = oauth.Token(key=oauth_token, secret=oauth_token_secret)
client = oauth.Client(consumer, access_token)

url = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json"
data = {'status': 'post this'}
response, data = client.request(url,'POST',urllib.urlencode(data))
```

Since oauth2 library is not available on GAE, I want to know the easiest means to be able to run the code on GAE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for this [exmpale](https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2/blob/master/example/appengine_oauth.py). Need to upload oauth2 folder along with your source.

Answer (score 1):

`oauth2` is a pure-python module; it should run fine on App Engine - just bundle it with your app.